missing z-value in 'logitr' package for wiliingness to pay
I'm researcher in economic analysis of green infrastructure.
I tried to use r package 'logitr' for estimating wtp of garden and green area.
but I couldn't get a clear results of z-value.
model fitting is done well.
how can I get a z-value and coefficient?
A tibble: 1,498 × 19
id idx Q8tt price choice alt age reg
1 1 1127 0 5000 0 1 3 7
2 1 1127 0 2000 1 2 3 7
3 2 412 0 5000 0 1 4 2
4 2 412 0 1000 1 2 4 2
5 3 418 0 5000 0 1 4 2
6 3 418 0 1000 1 2 4 2
7 4 410 0 5000 0 1 5 7
8 4 410 0 1000 1 2 5 7
9 5 218 0 5000 0 1 3 4
10 5 218 0 2000 1 2 3 4
11 more variables: edu , mar ,
bud , tran , time , area ,
satis , fee , gar , gre ,
act 
Using logitr version: 1.1.1
Call:
logitr(data = wtp2.7, outcome = "choice", obsID = "id", pars = c("price",
"age", "edu", "bud", "act", "gar", "gre"))
Frequencies of alternatives:
1 2
0.5514 0.4486
Exit Status: 3, Optimization stopped because ftol_rel or ftol_abs was reached.
Model Type: Multinomial Logit
Model Space: Preference
Model Run: 1 of 1
Iterations: 25
Elapsed Time: 0h:0m:0.02s
Algorithm: NLOPT_LD_LBFGS
Weights Used?: FALSE
Robust? FALSE
Model Coefficients:
Estimate Std. Error z-value Pr(>|z|)
price -0.00051319 NA NA NA
age 0.00000000 NA NA NA
edu 24.90583872 NA NA NA
bud 0.25813579 NA NA NA
act -6.32432679 NA NA NA
gar 0.00000000 NA NA NA
gre 14.52830879 NA NA NA
Log-Likelihood: -261.2535918
Null Log-Likelihood: -519.1672382
AIC: 536.5071836
BIC: 568.8384000
McFadden R2: 0.4967834
Adj McFadden R2: 0.4833002
Number of Observations: 749.0000000
